# How to make this InTx func (for SQL transactions) "safe" if there is a panic during callback?

Tags: go, error-handling, transactions

Playground link: https://go.dev/play/p/laQo-BfF7sK

It's subtle, but this InTx "context manager" (in transaction) has at least one bug. If there is a `panic` during the "Fun" call:

```golang
type Fun func(context.Context, *sql.Tx) error

func InTx(db *sql.DB, fn Fun) error {
    ctx := context.Background()
    t, err := db.BeginTx(ctx, nil)
    if err != nil {
        log.Panicln(err)
        return err
    }
    return safe(ctx, t, fn)
}

// safe should run the provided function in the context of a SQL transaction
// expect a nil error if (and only if) everything worked w/o incident
func safe(ctx context.Context, t *sql.Tx, fn Fun) (err error) {
    defer func() {
        if err == nil {
            err = t.Commit()
            return
        }
        if bad := t.Rollback(); bad != nil && bad != sql.ErrTxDone {
            err = fmt.Errorf("during rollback, panic(%v); err=%w", bad, err)
            // log error
            return
        }
    }()
    err = fn(ctx, t)
    return
}
```

Here is an example to demonstrate:

```golang
func main() {
    var db *sql.DB;
    // ...
    _ = InTx(db, func(ctx context.Context, t *sql.Tx) error {
        // ... lots more SQL executed here ...
        if _, err := t.Exec("DELETE FROM products"); err != nil {
            return err
        }
        // ...
        panic("will cause Commit")
        // should expect Rollback() instead, as if we:
        //return nil
    })
}
```

Related: Would it be inappropriate to panic during another panic, e.g. if Rollback fails? If so, why? (or when not)

Comment: Many a Go programmer subscribe to the theory of `panic` ONLY when unavoidable, and it's also wisest to "handle errors instead of checking" them. Therefore, I'd reckon that panic-recover and re-panic is decidedly unusual. Best to just handle the error, if you can, esp. because panic will continue to disrupt the routine, so such an interruption ought to happen at most once-ish.

Answer (score 0):

Adding `recover` in another `defer` (after the first one in the `safe` function, since they unwind in stack order) would guard against an "inner" `panic` from the callback, but that may be sub-optimal or less idiomatic that other approaches.

```
defer func() {
    if veryBad := recover(); veryBad != nil {
        bad := t.Rollback()
        err = fmt.Errorf("aborted SQL due to panic: %v; err=%w", veryBad, bad)
        // log error, should re-panic here?
        return
    }
}()
```

I'd be very happy to accept someone else's Go wisdom in lieu of my potentially-flawed approach.

Comment: Another solution is using a private or typed error to define a "sentinel" prior to calling `fn` that can help the defer'd code detect the panic case, or other cases where the assignment of err would otherwise leave it nil. i.e. `err = notNil # before err = fn(...)`

Comment: I do think there are flaws with each approach, not to mention readability woes. Is there any simple Go idiom for the catch, checkpoint, and re-throw pattern we might desire here?